# invoke webservices in UCM using .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm new in UCM I trying to invoke webservices in UCM using .net I got this error message

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Source Error:
           return base.Channel.QuickSearch(request);

```
        IdcProperty extra = new IdcProperty();
        extra.name = "dID";
        extra.value = "210";
        IdcProperty[] array = { extra };
        IdcPropertyCollection _IdcPC = new IdcPropertyCollection();


        QuickSearchRequest search = new QuickSearchRequest(searchWord, _IdcPC);
        QuickSearchResult result = new QuickSearchResult();

        ((ClientBase<ISearchSoap>)(client)).ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("?", "?"); 

        result = client.QuickSearch(searchWord, _IdcPC);
```